# Fix WP Redirect Loop

Tags: wp-redirect

I want to redirect the URLs that have '/ur/' to URLs without '/ur/' if it is not a single post or page. But the following code gives too many redirects error. 
These '/ur/' to URLs are added by qTranslate and I want translation functionality only on single posts and pages.

```
   function checks_on_page_load() { 

    $sUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  

        if (strpos($sUrl, '/ur') !== false && !is_singular( array( 'post', 'page' ))) { 
          $sUrl = str_replace("/ur","",$sUrl); 

        if ( wp_redirect( $sUrl) ) { 
        exit; 
    }     

    }         
    } 

    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'checks_on_page_load' );
```

Comment: Can you directly access a page that _doesn't_ have `/ur/`? They might be redirecting to `/ur/` so this will create an infinite loop.

Comment: note that it will be impossible to reach pages with names such as urdu, urgent, urns, urning, uruguay, ustron, etc etc. Also you should indent your code. That should also be a `wp_safe_redirect` call to prevent hijacking